# Etymology of the word 코끼리 (elephant)?

Tags: word-origin

I'm assuming that 코 is the same 코 meaning 'nose'. What about '끼리'? is it the same 끼리 meaning that something is true of a type or group? or is it some form of 길다 ('long')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

second guess is right. it changed for long time but 코(nose) + 끼(was 길 which means length) + -이

It was 고키리 and currently changed to 코끼리, but same meaning.

> 1) ‘코끼리’는 ‘코가 긴 것, 코가 긴 짐승’이라는 뜻으로 ‘고ㅎ + 길- + -이’의 구성으로 만들어진 것이다. ‘고ㅎ’는 ‘코’를 가리키는 단어였고, ‘길-’은 ‘長’의 뜻을, ‘-이’는 ‘것, 짐승’의 뜻을 나타낸다.
>    ‘코끼리’의 어형으로 나타나는 것은 훈민정음으로 표기된 초기의 문헌인 <월인석보>에 ‘고키리’의 형태로 나타났다. ‘고기리, 코기리, 코길이’와 같은 형태는 ‘코가 긴 것’이라는 뜻을 드러낸 것이다. ‘코’를 나타내는 형태가 ‘고ㅎ’에서 ‘코’로 바뀌면서 ‘코키리, 코이, 코끼리’로 변하게 된다.
>    15세기의 ‘고키리’에서 현대의 ‘코끼리’에 이르기까지 의미는 변화하지 않았다.

ref :

1)http://www.korean.go.kr/front/wordLocal/wordHistoryList.do?mn_id=116
2)https://twitter.com/urimal365/status/423322686983401472?lang=ko

Answer (score 7):

The derivation is likely [to have to come from 길다](https://twitter.com/urimal365/status/423322686983401472?lang=ko). The linked Tweet states that 곻, being the attested form of 코, evolved with 길- and the general nominalising suffix 이 to form 고키리 (the form [attested](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=2946800) in the 1459 월인석보 《月印釋譜》) then becoming 코키리 and ending up with 코끼리.